# Different behavior of a loop in a function when else clause is added

Tags: python

There's a simple function:

```py
users = [
    (['bmiller', 'Miller, Brett'], 'Brett Miller'),
    (['Gianni Tina', 'tgiann', 'tgianni'], 'Tina Gianni'),
    (['mplavis', 'marcusp', 'Plavis, Marcus'], 'Marcus Plavis')
]


def replace_user_login_with_name(login):
    name = ''
    for u in users:
        if login in u[0]:
            name = str(login).replace(login, u[1])
        else:                  # without these lines
            name = str(login)  # it works fine

    return name
```

It was working just fine, replacing logins with full names of users when executed without the `else` clause (marked with the comments in the markup above):

```py
full_name = replace_user_login_with_name('bmiller')
print(full_name)
# 'Brett Miller'
```

But after adding the `else` clause to just return user's login when given user is not present in the `users` array, all entries are returned as logins, so:

```py
full_name = replace_user_login_with_name('bmiller')
print(full_name)
# 'bmiller'
```

Why the `else` clause gets executed even if logins are matched?

Comment: Yo never `break` the loop when a match is found. The `else` body should be triggered when no match is found *at all*, but you rub it for every possible login.

Comment: Because the `else` is attached to the `if`, not the `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return name after a match is found:

```
users = [
    (['bmiller', 'Miller, Brett'], 'Brett Miller'),
    (['Gianni Tina', 'tgiann', 'tgianni'], 'Tina Gianni'),
    (['mplavis', 'marcusp', 'Plavis, Marcus'], 'Marcus Plavis')
]


def replace_user_login_with_name(login):
    name = ''
    for u in users:
        if login in u[0]:
            name = str(login).replace(login, u[1])
            return name
        else:                  # without these lines
            name = str(login)  # it works fine

    return name
```